# php mod_rewrite Permalinks

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I am looking for a way to access to:

```
 http://myurl.com/?file=random_token
```

with

```
 http://myurl.com/random_token/
```

I already read about mod_rewrite in the .**htaccess** but I don't know how to setup the pattern.

I tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /(.*)/$ /index.php?file=$1
```

It would be nice if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?file=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's nearly perfect. How do I handle existing folders?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCOnd %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?([a-z-]+) index.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```